# How to mount an ext3 VMware Virtual Disk Image (vmdk)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-player

I found a wiki entry on how to mount an [NTFS VMware Virtual Disk Image](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-mount-ntfs-vmware-virtual-disk-image-vmdk-readwrite.html) (vmdk) and another [link](http://www.vladan.fr/mounting-your-vmdk-disks-directly-to-your-windows-box-how-to/). I want to mount an ext3 vmdk file on Windows XP. How can I do that?

> The VMware-mount-5.5.0-18463.exe utility mounts NTFS filesystems
>   created with vmplayer 3.0.0 build-197124.

Answer (score 2):

you need vmware mount, and an [ext3 driver](http://ext2fsd.sourceforge.net/projects/projects.htm#ext2fsd). Mount the drive with vmware mount, and as long as you have a driver that works, it should be readable.

Comment: tried using vmware-mount.exe with the ext2fsd by first mounting the vmdk with  vmware-mount.exe on z: and then running ext2fsd. ext3 wasn't detected..

Comment: It works here. You just have to make sure the ext2fsd driver service is started. Starting the Ext2 Volume Manager does not automatically start the service, you may have to start it manually in Tools/Service Management depending on the settings chosen during setup.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you were using XP. My comment "it works here" referred to W7 x64 (and also a later ext2fsd version given how old the question is). Tech is slowly getting better...

Comment: At that time, I'm pretty sure I had gotten it working with XP. Its been 3 years and a bit, so I might be wrong ;p